# Is there support for paging with OData in Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I can see there is support for offset/limit when accessing a Cosmos DB in Azure via the SQL API - but does OData support this yet?

Comment: Why not use the SDK?

Comment: @ravitella - thanks for the reply, which SDK?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The specific use in your project may need to be adjusted, and it is supported in the web api project.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? I don't know if my plan is useful to you, I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can download [my demo](https://github.com/Jason446620/ODataWithWebApiQuerySupportSkip) in github. And [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-with-odata-and-Asp-Net-web-api/) and [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options) can help u.

*Data in My Storage account*

[image]

*Test by postman*

[image]

***TestDataController.cs***

```
public class TestDataController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=***x=core.windows.net");
        CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        //table name
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
        // all datas in table
        IQueryable<CustomerEntity> linqQuery = table.CreateQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(x => x.PartitionKey != "0")
        .Select(x => new CustomerEntity() { PartitionKey = x.PartitionKey, RowKey = x.RowKey, Name = x.Name, Role = x.Role });
        // test data
        //var result = CreateTestData().AsQueryable();
        // real data in `test` table
        var a = linqQuery.ToList<CustomerEntity>().AsQueryable();
        return Ok(a);
    }

    public List<TestData> CreateTestData()
    {
        List<TestData> data = new List<TestData>();
        data.Add(new TestData { Id = 1, Name = "Jignesh", Role = "Project Manager" });
        data.Add(new TestData { Id = 2, Name = "Tejas", Role = "Architect" });
        data.Add(new TestData { Id = 3, Name = "Rakesh", Role = "Lead" });

        return data;
    }
}
```

***WebApiConfig.cs***

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
        config.EnsureInitialized();
       

    }
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "WebAPITest";
        builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";
        builder.EntitySet<TestData>("TestData");
        // you can dynamic load entitys later
        builder.EntitySet<CustomerEntity>("CustomerEntity");
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return edmModel;
    }
}
```

**PRIVIOUS**

I am not clear about this solution. What application will you use, desktop or web application?

If your app is web application, you can see these article.([offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging) , [Paging With OData And ASP.NET Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-with-odata-and-Asp-Net-web-api/) )

If your app not web application. I suggest u use `linq` to solve the issue.

[image]

[image]

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Azure Cosmos Table Samples");
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*****fix=core.windows.net");
        CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
        IQueryable<CustomerEntity> linqQuery = table.CreateQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(x => x.PartitionKey != "0")
        .Select(x => new CustomerEntity() { PartitionKey = x.PartitionKey, RowKey = x.RowKey, Name = x.Name });
       // skip and take method 
       var c = linqQuery.ToList<CustomerEntity>().Skip(3).Take(1).ToList<CustomerEntity>();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason! Appreciate the reply. The problem is I have an OData query that I'd like to defer to the server/Cosmos DB. The client (js library) generates a long list of filters etc. along with paging details (skip/take), Right now, to query the Cosmos DB, I'm breaking that down to manually convert it into SQL. That's not a great approach, so would like to simply just pass the OData query to Cosmos. I know I can do this using EF, but I haven't seen that support skip take.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ If you have time, you can download the sample in the webapi I provided to view, which supports skip. I just tried the simulated data, but it is normal to query the data in Cosmos. 406 Error, you will first try and I will follow up .