# Apply filter to fetch records from Azure Storage Table

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Need records from Azure Storage Table.
Either need to apply filter on storage table OR first get all records in code and apply filter.
Result should have records (all fields) only for ID, whose RelatedTypes must have entry in table with this ID.
Eg: ID = 3 having RelatedTypes = "A,B" Now if we have rows with ID=1, Type="A" and ID=1, Type="B" then only rows belongs to ID=3 should come in result.

Storage Table Sample:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkzEt.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you show in your picture is in conflict with your description. Can't understand what you want?

Comment: The key point of your question is how to use filters to obtain data? Or how to filter data according to your custom rules (essentially not related to table-storage)? These are two problems.

Comment: If it is simply how to filter the data, there are currently two types, one is `restapi` and the other is `linq`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047510/is-there-support-for-paging-with-odata-in-cosmos-db/62057377#62057377  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925442/console-app-to-use-azure-storage-tableapi/61929744#61929744

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Whether the link I provided is helpful to you, I look forward to your reply.