# Is there any work around in azure api with offset 101 and above

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

when I tried to fetch the records from cosmos DB with offset value more than 100 using azure API, it returns an empty list though there are values. when using the generated query from code with the portal it returning the proper results.

The generated query from code:
SELECT o.id from order o where o.versionId =1 AND o.resource.customer.id ='someid' order by o.resource.createdOn desc offset 100 limit 100

Comment: which SDK version are you using? OFFSET/LIMIT was added about a year ago and older clients might see strange behaviors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047510/is-there-support-for-paging-with-odata-in-cosmos-db/62057377#62057377

Comment: Do the `skip` and `top` in this post meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

The issue is fixed by adding the maxItemCount(value) to FeedOptions.

example:

```
FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions();
options.maxItemCount(1000);
FeedResponse<Document> feedResponse = documentClient
                .queryDocuments(String.format("collectionLink", databaseId, collectionName), query, options)
```